# Oracle trigger that check constraint on a monthly basis

Tags: oracle, count, constraints

just wonder is it possible to create a trigger to check on a specify constraint base on monthly basis.

eg. 
table rent 
|ID|Member|book|
----------------------
1  | John |fairytale|

2  | John |friction|

3  | John |comic|

4  | John |magazine|

constraint : member are only allow to borrow 4 books monthly.

i thought of using count(book) <= 4 but does not know how to implement the monthly basis constraint.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How you are planning to access your table from the application? Because idea of trigger might not be a good idea for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a trigger, whilst it seems to work, is a dangerous way of doing it, as sessions running in parallel wont see the inserted data from the inprogress session. 
you can do it via a materilized view:

```
SQL> create table rent (id number primary key, member varchar2(30), book varchar2(20), date_rented date);

Table created.

SQL> create index rent_ix1 on rent ( member, date_rented);

Index created.

SQL> create materialized view log on rent with rowid(member,date_rented)
  2  including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view rent_month_check
  2  refresh fast on commit
  3  as
  4  select trunc(date_rented, 'mm') month, member, count(*) rentals
  5    from rent
  6   group by trunc(date_rented, 'mm'), member;

Materialized view created.

SQL> alter table rent_month_check
  2  add constraint rent_month_check_ck1 check (rentals <= 4);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into rent values(1, 'DazzaL', 'crime', sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into rent values(2, 'DazzaL', 'mystery', sysdate+1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into rent values(3, 'DazzaL', 'fantasy', sysdate+2);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into rent values(4, 'DazzaL', 'politics', sysdate+3);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into rent values(5, 'DazzaL', 'thriller', sysdate+4);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.RENT_MONTH_CHECK_CK1) violated


SQL> select * from rent_month_check;

MONTH     MEMBER                            RENTALS
--------- ------------------------------ ----------
01-NOV-12 DazzaL                                  4
```

Comment: Hi dazzal, thanks for the recommendation. does that means we cannot use trigger to check constraint for multi user? if the session only allows one user to access at a time, then is workable?

Comment: my answer is workable in multi user. yes, using a trigger will allow incorrect data in multi user. why would you implement a trigger though with that known flaw? do you perceive issues with a materialised view?

Comment: no dazzal, i think your method will work. just that i want to experiment trigger function first.

Answer (score 1):

If the table stores only actual data then it is quite simple:

```
create or replace trigger tr_rent
before insert on rent
for each row 
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  select count(*) into v_count
  from rent where member = :new.member;

  if v_count >= 4 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Limit reached');
  end if;
end;
/
```

But if the table store historical data as well then you need some timestamp column, f.e. rent_date. So the count-query should be changed to the following:

```
select count(*) into v_count
from rent where member = :new.member
and rent_date > add_months(sysdate, -1);
```

In some cases reading a table that is currently being modified may lead to "mutating table error", but the trigger above is safe.

Comment: its not a good idea to do this in a trigger. the solution will fail if 2+ sessions are inserting in parallel. you'd either need to update a summary table or use a materialised view to do this properly.

Comment: The solution will also fail with ORA-04091 as you're reading from the table that being inserted into in a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: DazzaL, yep, mview approach is more rational. 

Ben, I've just tested and there is no any errors. Oracle 11.2.0.3

Comment: hi @hilton, thanks for the reply. rent_date > previous month = checking the constraint monthly? sorry i'm quite new to oracle.

Comment: i tried this code but it does not work in my table, my table consist of 5 column - recordid, booktitle, author, member, rent_date. so how do i implement it?