# Constrain number of rows in table, by value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table called ward (dealing with hospitals):

```
Create table ward(
    Wno varchar(15) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(20) Not Null,
    Number_of_beds integer Not Null
);
```

And a table for patients:

```
Create table patient(
    Pid varchar(15) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(20) Not Null,
    Address varchar(50) Not Null,
    Date_of_birth date Not Null
 );
```

I need to constrain the patients somehow so that if a patient is assigned to a specific ward then the number of patients can't exceed the number of beds in the ward.
I thought of adding the Wno as a foreign key to the patient table, but don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: What is that 'student' doing in your patient table? :P well you can add `Wno` into patient that allows better relation between the two entities.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, was meant to be be if a patient was assigned :P

Comment: @CraigTraynor:What is your oracle version?

Comment: Oracle database 11g express edition release 11.2.0.2.0 - 6

Comment: @CraigTraynor:Its better to add another column ,wno to patients table.Which means that the patients is assigned to which ward.While inserting there will be a trigger which check the patients table where total patients assgined to that particular ward is less that total number of beds in ward table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the foreign key into patient table as following. Apology this query is in MYSQL. I noticed that you need Oracle though. However the logic is similar :) The syntax needs changes.

```
Create table ward(
    Wno varchar(15) Not null Primary Key,
    Name varchar(20) Not Null,
    Number_of_beds integer Not Null
);
```

And a table for patients:

```
Create table patient(
    Pid varchar(15) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(20) Not Null,
    Address varchar(50) Not Null,
    Date_of_birth date Not Null,
    WardNo varchar(15),
    foreign key (wardno) references ward (wno)  ' -- adds the foreign key relation
 );
```

In order to check if ward is full, you can have an `insert` or `update trigger`

Free bed count can be obtained by following query:

```
SELECT p.wardno, (w.number_of_beds - count(pid)) as freebeds
from patient as p
left join ward as w
on p.wardno = w.wno
group by wardno
```

Now we create a trigger to check if any patient is going into a ward whre freebed count = 0.

**Updated to Oracle Version**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FreeBedsWardTrigger
       BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
       ON patient
       FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
       max_beds    INTEGER;    -- max number of beds for the ward
       used_beds   INTEGER;    -- used beds for the ward
    BEGIN
       SELECT   COUNT (pid)
         INTO   used_beds
         FROM   patient
        WHERE   wardno = :NEW.wardno;

       SELECT   number_of_beds
         INTO   max_beds
         FROM   ward
        WHERE   wno = :NEW.wardno;

       IF (max_beds - used_beds) > 0
       THEN
          RETURN;
       ELSE
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-100100,
                                   'No more beds available in this ward.');
       END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sathya for validating it and adding the heading for OP's reference. I just wrote it out of memory on PL/SQL. :) So I didn't dare declaring it as correct syntax

Comment: it was [converted to PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13701497/revisions) by [@Gaurav](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1138658/gaurav-soni), I just formatted it a bit better. Due credit to him :)

Comment: using triggers to enforce this is a sure fire way to, one day, having the rule broken. using triggers is only "OK" if you serialise access to the table (eg an API which obtains a lock prior to inserting+determining counts etc). Think what happens when 2 sessions perform the insert before either one of them commits their transaction.

Comment: @DazzaL meaning, we need to have a lock implemented in the trigger on the tables before insert/update. Is that what you meant? Great point. :) +1 First come first serve on hospital addmission :P

Comment: @Sathya and Gaurav. Thanks mate. I should find a MySQL -> Oracle converter :)

Comment: @bonCodigo you'd need to lock somewhere yes. I personally prefer materialized views for this type of enforcement or an API that uses a lock (eg select for update on the ward table for that ward id or using a named dbms_lock). eg mat view approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349350/oracle-trigger-that-check-constraint-on-a-monthly-basis/13350596#13350596